# Error on flash loan contract testing it on Kovan when increasing the amount of the lend

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/creating-a-flash-loan-using-aave) on Kovan Netork using Remix... The first contract I created worked fine (contract address is 0x567B73a65E211a62966772071C156A5B2Ecdc21F) - I made a loan of 1 DAI (asset address 0xFf795577d9AC8bD7D90Ee22b6C1703490b6512FD). However when I change the flashloan.sol file, its line 39 to (which was supposed to loan the value of ):

> uint amount = 100 ether;

.. It does not work.

The contract 0x97D3f2072a77712B04D6065A0584C0a287EBddfe was created with this modification, in order to loan 100 DAI, however I get an error when I try it.

I tried to debug on tenderly where I get the error "SafeMath: subtraction overflow":

[image]

Is it a bug?